# Is it possible to reference a linkbotton outside an update panel as the update trigger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, webforms

THIS IS THE SITE.MASTER ASPX PAGE

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Prototype4.SiteMaster" %>
```

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

alert("JS code in general: OK");
            $(function () {
                $("#lnkShowOtherPage").click(function () {
                    alert("OtherPagePanel length: " + $("#OtherPagePanel").length);
                    alert("OtherPagePanel load: " + $("#OtherPagePanel").load);
                    $("#OtherPagePanel").load("/EntryForms/OpenCase.aspx");
                });
            });

```
    function updateClock() {
        var currentTime = new Date();

        var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
        var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
        var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

        // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
        currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
        currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

        // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
        var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";

        // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
        currentHours = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

        // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
        currentHours = (currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

        // Compose the string for display
        var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;

        // Update the time display
        document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
    }
```

**Case Management System**
            
            
                 
            
            
                
                    
                        
                            Welcome  
                                !
                        [  ]
                            <%--Welcome: 
                             !--%>
                        
                        
                            Welcome: Guest
                            [ Log In ]

```
                </asp:LoginView>
                <%--&nbsp;&nbsp; [&nbsp;<asp:LoginStatus ID="MasterLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/Logout.aspx" />&nbsp;]&nbsp;&nbsp;--%>

            </div>
            <div class="topNav">
            <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" 
                        ImageUrl="~/homeIcon.png"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="About" 
                        ImageUrl="~/aboutIcon.png"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem ImageUrl="~/contact_us_icon1.png" NavigateUrl="~/Contact.aspx" 
                        Text="Contact Us" Value="Contact Us"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
            </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
            </div>

            </div>
            <div class="page" style="margin-top:5px;height:auto;">

            <div class="right" style="border-style:solid;padding-left: 4px; padding-right:4px;">
                <asp:Button ID="newsButton" runat="server" Text="News" 
                        class="fnctButton" Height="25px" Width="70px" />
                <div style="border-color: White; border-width:medium; border: medium;"> 
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.2em; color:White;">
                    This is a place holder for some real text that is displayed regarding news within the departement and additional links to external sites for news.
                </p>
                </div>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="RightNewsItem" runat="server"/>           

            </div>
            <div class="left" style="border-style:solid;">
                <asp:Button ID="functionButton" runat="server" Text="System Functions" 
                        class="fnctButton" Height="25px" Width="170px" />

                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="LeftNavigation" runat="server">            


                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
            <div class="middle" style= "border-bottom-style:solid;">
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
            </div>
            </div>



    <div class="clear">
    </div>

    <div class="footer">

        <span style="font-size: small;color: #FFFFFF;"><strong>Copyright 2011 JustRite Software Inc.</strong></span></div>
</form>
```

AND THIS ONE IS THE CASE ADMIN PAGE BASED ON THE MASTER PAGE. THERE ARE TWO BUTTONS ON THE LEFT NAVIGATION PANE THAT SHOULD LOAD A THIRD PAGE (OPENCASE OR ADDEXHIBIT) IN THE CENTRE SPACE DEPENDING ON WHICH BUTTON IS CLICKED. THE CASE ADMIN PAGE .ASPX BELOW.

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CaseAdmin.aspx.cs" Inherits="Prototype4.CaseAdmin" %>
<%@PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/Account/Login.aspx"%>

```
<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">
<p class="actionButton">        

        <a id="lnkShowOtherPage" href="#">Open Case</a> 
</p>
<p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="RegisterExhibitLinkButton" 
        runat="server" onclick="RegisterExhibitLinkButton_Click">Register Exhibit</asp:LinkButton> </p>
</div>
```

```
<div id="OtherPagePanel" style="width:auto">

</div>
```

THIS SECTION REPRESENTS THE CODE BEHIND FOR THE CASEADMIN PAGE THUS THE .CS CODES

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Prototype4
{
    public partial class CaseAdmin : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        //string userid;
        //string strUsername;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //strUsername = Session["Username"].ToString();
        }
        //public String AdminUserID
        //{
        //    get
        //    {
        //        //return userid;
        //    }
        //}

```
        //userid = PreviousPage.AdminID;


        //Response.Redirect("~/EntryForms/OpenCase.aspx", false);


        /* if (PreviousPage != null)
         {
             TextBox SourceTextBox =
                 (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("UserName");
             if (SourceTextBox != null)
             {
                 userid = SourceTextBox.ToString();
             }
         }*/


    protected void RegisterExhibitLinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/EntryForms/AddExhibit.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

}

THIS IS ONE OF THE TWO PAGES THAT SHOULD LOAD DEPENDING ON THE BUTTON CLICK. I HAVE ATTACHED THE CODE FOR THE OPENCASE FORM SO THAT WOULD CORRESPOND WITH THE OPENCASE LINK BUTTON ON THE LEFT. OPENCASE.ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OpenCase.aspx.cs" Inherits="Prototype4.EntryForms.OpenCase" %>
```

<%@PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/CaseAdmin.aspx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

.casePage
        {
            width: 430px;
            height:314px;
            background-color:#3a4f63;
        }
        .style1
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .style2
        {
            font-weight: normal;
            color: Black;
            text-align: left;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top:0px;

```
    }
    .style3
    {
        width: 85%;
    }
    .style4
    {
        width: 175px;
        background-color: #808080;
    }
    .style5
    {
        background-color: #CCCCCC;
        padding-left:10px;
    }
</style>
```

**Open Case
        Form**

```
    <table class="style3" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">
                <p class="style2">
                Case ID:    
                </p>
        </td>
            <td class="style5">
        <asp:TextBox ID="caseIDTextBox" 
            runat="server" height="22px" width="154px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">
                <p class="style2">
                Case Description:
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="style5">
                <asp:TextBox ID="caseDescTextBox" 
            runat="server" height="22px" width="154px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">
               <p class="style2">
                Case Administrator ID:
                </p>
            </td>
            <td class="style5">
                <asp:TextBox 
            ID="caseAdminIDTextBox" runat="server" height="22px" width="154px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>






        </div>
        <div>


            <table class="style3" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <asp:Button ID="openCaseBotton" runat="server" Text="Open Case" 
                            onclick="openCaseBotton_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="center">
                        <asp:Button ID="addExhibitBotton" runat="server" Text="Add Exhibit" 
                            onclick="addExhibitBotton_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td align="right">
                        <asp:Button ID="cancelButton" runat="server" Text="Cancel" 
                            onclick="cancelButton_Click" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>


        </div>
</div>
</form>
```

AND LASTLY THE OPENCASE.CS PAGE

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;

namespace Prototype4.EntryForms
{
    public partial class OpenCase : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string adminString;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            adminString = "CA123";
        }

```
    protected void openCaseBotton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //SQL connection string
        SqlDataSource CSMDataSource = new SqlDataSource();
        CSMDataSource.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CMSSQL3ConnectionString"].ToString();

        //SQL Insert command with variables
        CSMDataSource.InsertCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;
        CSMDataSource.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO Filing (FilingID, FilingDesc, DateOpened, FilingPriority, AdministratorID) VALUES (@FilingID, @FilingDesc, @DateOpened, @FilingPriority, @AdministratorID)";

        //Actual Insertion with values from textboxes into databse fields
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("FilingID", caseIDTextBox.Text);
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("FilingDesc", caseDescTextBox.Text);
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("DateOpened", DateTime.Now.ToString());
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("FilingPriority", null);
        CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("AdministratorID", adminString.ToString());

        int rowsCommitted = 0;

        //Try catch method to catch exceptions during insert
        try
        {
            rowsCommitted = CSMDataSource.Insert();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //error message displayed when exception occurs


            string script = "<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>";
            Response.Write("The following Error occurred while entering the records into the database" + " " + ex.ToString() + " ");
            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx", false);
        }
        finally
        {
            CSMDataSource = null;
        }

        //Where to go next if insert was successful or failed
        if (rowsCommitted != 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/CaseAdmin.aspx", false);
        }
        else
        {

            Response.Redirect("~/ErrorPage.aspx", false);
        }

    }

    protected void addExhibitBotton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/EntryForms/AddExhibit.aspx", false);

    }

    protected void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/CaseAdmin.aspx", false);
    }
}
```

}

ALL I WANT TO DO IS GET THE RESPECTIVE PAGES TO LOAD INSIDE THE MAIN CONTENT AREA (THE MIDDLE SECTION) WITHOUT RELOADING THE PAGE. ITS BEEN A LONG WAY COMING BUT PROVED SUCCESSFUL WITH A LOT TO LEARN BUT I JUST WANT TO KNOW HOW I CAN APPLY THIS SAME TECHNIQUE TO THE OTHER BUTTON CLICK(ADD EXHIBIT) SINCE IN THE AJAX CODE IN THE HEADER OF THE MASTER PAGE SPECIFIES THE URL ON JUST ONE PAGE. HOW DO I DO THAT FOR SUBSEQUENT PAGES THAT USE THE MASTER PAGE AND WOULD BE DOING SIMILAR ACTIONS. FOR EXAMPLE THE CASE MANAGER PAGE THAT LOOKS LIKE THIS.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CaseManager.aspx.cs" Inherits="Prototype4.CaseManager" %>
```

This is a place holder for allerts about cases to which the investigator has been assigned to.

```
    <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-bottom:20px;">    
<p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="AllocateOfficerLinkButton" runat="server">Allocate Officer</asp:LinkButton> </p>
<p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="ReallocateLinkButton" runat="server">Reallocate Officer</asp:LinkButton> </p>
<p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="SetPriorityLinkButton" runat="server">Prioritize Case</asp:LinkButton> </p>
<p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="OpenCaseLinkButton" runat="server">Open Case</asp:LinkButton> </p>
<p class="actionButton"><asp:LinkButton ID="RegisterExhibitLinkButton" runat="server">Register Exhibit</asp:LinkButton> </p>
</div>
```

I WANT TO TO DO SOMETHING SIMILAR LIKE IN THE CASE ADMIN PAGE BUT AM WONDERING WHAT THE CODES WILL ADD UP TO BE LIKE IN THE MASTER PAGE.

THANKS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I actually just wanted to load a form
>   that is created in another asp. page
>   into the main content area...

I fear that what you need is not `UpdatePanel` but rather "ordinary" AJAX loading that other page contents into some element.. using jQuery it's as simple as:

```
$("#OtherPagePanel").load("OtherPage.aspx");
```

Where `OtherPagePanel` is the ID of some element in your `.aspx` code.

You can pass parameters to the other page over the URL, if you need to Post data it's still possible but requires some extra lines - let us know in such case.

Edit:

In the placeholder where you want the data from other page to appear, have this:

```
<div id="OtherPagePanel"></div>
```

Have such link in the other placeholder: (no need in LinkButton, ordinary HTML link is enough)

```
<a id="lnkShowOtherPage" href="#">Show other page</a>
```

Now in the `<head>` section of your master page add this code and it's all done:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#lnkShowOtherPage").click(function() {
        $("#OtherPagePanel").load("OtherPage.aspx");
    });
});
</script>
```

You can also copy the `jQuery.min.js` file to your own server and change the `src` accordingly.

Edit 2:

In order to debug add such lines to the code, it will tell what went wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("JS code in general: OK");
$(function() {
    alert("Page load: OK");
    $("#lnkShowOtherPage").click(function() {
        alert("Link click: OK");
        $("#OtherPagePanel").load("OtherPage.aspx");
    });
});
</script>
```

Reload the page and let us know what alerts you get.

Edit 3:

Based on the previous debug results, have this code now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#lnkShowOtherPage").click(function() {
        alert("OtherPagePanel length: " + $("#OtherPagePanel").length);
        alert("OtherPagePanel load: " + $("#OtherPagePanel").load);
        $("#OtherPagePanel").load("OtherPage.aspx");
    });
});
</script>
```

Edit 4 and hopefully last:

In order to load different page into different `div` by clicking different button in addition to everything you already have, have such code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#lnkShowOtherPage").click(function() {
        $("#OtherPagePanel").load("OtherPage.aspx");
    });

    $("#lnkShowDifferentOtherPage").click(function() {
        $("#DifferentOtherPagePanel").load("DifferentOtherPage.aspx");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: that was one of the recommendations i got but havent tried it out yet since am not familiar with the procedure but am willing to learn immediately. My current .aspx page is based on a master page and it has a content place holder where i want the changes to take place. the button to trigger this changes is in another content place holder. Id be very glad if you can guide me on the steps that i need to follow to get it to work. thanks for your patience and atention

Comment: Whew...this aint no easy task... I tried your version exactly as you had recommended only replacing otherpage.aspx with the page i want displayed and changing the link button to a hyperlink text. i runned the form and clicked the link but nothing happened. I also did further research and found something similar from this page (http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/jquery/jquerypart2.aspx) i tried that one too but the result was the same...nothing happened. though it compiled successfully and there were no page errors displayed at runtime. what could i be leaving out.??

Comment: this is what it looks like:  <a id="lnkShowOtherPage" href="#">Open Case</a>  for the link and then: <div id="OtherPagePanel" style="width:auto">    
    </div> for the div area where the new content should appear and then : <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#lnkShowOtherPage").click(function () {
                    $("#OtherPagePanel").load("OtherPage.aspx");
                });
            });
        </script> for the head section of the master page.

Comment: @Sel see my second edit.. programming isn't easy task indeed, debug is crucial part of it.

Comment: When i load the page the first alert pops up showing "JS code in general ok". i click ok and the form loads into the browser and displays "Page load ok". I hit ok again and proceed to click on the link and it displays the message "link click ok" and nothing happens afterwards... i tried it over and over again but it was the same results...:(

Comment: @Sel time for further debug.. see my new edit, have the new code in place and tell what you see in the two alerts when clicking the link. Also, browse directly to the `otherpage.aspx` and make sure you're getting anything - what you'll see in the browser is what you should get into the div. I know that all of this look tedious right now, but after you do this once or twice you'll see it becomes more simple and you'll learn to do that on your own.  :)

Comment: Thanks very much Wiz, am willing to learn no matter what it takes. I did a check on the "OthePage"and it works fine so i went ahead and runned the form. browser loads and before anything appeared, a message pops up saying "JS code in general:OK". I click okay and the form is displayed in the browser. i proceed to click the link and another message pops up saying "OtherPagePanel length:1". After clicking ok, a new message instantly shows.Its very long so id have to show it in the next comment.wish you could see a screen shot of it but couldnt get the jpeg here. anyway the message reads as below

Comment: OtherPagePanel load: function(a,b,d){if(typeofa!=="string")return zb.call(this,a);else if(!this.length)return this;var f=a.indexOf(" ");if(f>=0){vare=a.slice(f,a.length);a=a.slice(0,f)}f="GET";if(b)if(c.isFunction(b){d=b;b=null}else if(typeof b==="object"){b=c.param(b,c.ajaxSettings.traditional);f="pOST"}var j=this;c.ajax({url:a,type:f,dataType:"html",data:b,complete:function(i,o){if(o==="success"||o==="notmodified")j.html(e?c("<div
/>").append(i.responseText.replace(tb,"")).find(e):i.responseText);d&&j.each(d,[i.responseText,o,i])}});return this}

Comment: So i click ok from the long message and nothing happens. Does the last message depict any errors? am trying to load a new form into the div space. could that be the problem? i hope not. cant wait to try what's next.

Comment: @Sel you didn't have to post the whole function.. anyway you can edit your original post and add pictures in there next. As for the problem, I'm currently as baffled as you, time to take a step back. Instead of the line `$("#OtherPagePanel").load("OtherPage.aspx");` have this: `$("#OtherPagePanel").html("hello world");` - do you see the text "hello world" appear in the div now after clicking the link?

Comment: YES..."hello world" appears... what next then??? i feel the solution is really close....

Comment: @Sel silly question.. what exactly did you replace `OtherPage.aspx` with? Can you post it here please?

Comment: sure...previously i used to replace it with this code $("#OtherPagePanel").html("~/EntryForms/OpenCase.aspx"); but later u asked me to change to hello world which worked and this what what it looked like $("#OtherPagePanel").html("Hello world");.. but then we used to have .load too instead of the now .html

Comment: And oh! Wizzy...I updated the question with the edited set of codes on my MASTERPAGE and the subsequent page (CaseAdmin.aspx) and also a snapshot of the page i want loaded into the div section. I hope it helps us tackle this error down...

Comment: @Sel - As I thought, it was something rather silly.. the `~` character is not "supported" by client side script, so you can have only `$("#OtherPagePanel").load("/EntryForms/OpenCase.aspx");` which should finally work, assuming EntryForms folder is inside the website root. If still no luck edit your question with the full file structure of your website.

Comment: Splendid...it really works...unbelievable ...haha...but the alerts...hehe..and oh! So if i wanted to do the same thing on another button click id have to add the same code again in the master page but only changing the url? could there be and if statement to handle that?

Comment: I ADDED THE FULL PAGE CODES OF ABOUT 4 PAGES THAT ARE RELATED...HOPE TO APPLY THE AJAX CODE TO PERFORM THE SAME TASK ON ALL OF THEM.....THANKS VERY MUCH SHADOW WIZARD...YOUR WIZARDRY IS INDEED THE NEXT LEVEL...LOL..

Comment: @Sel cheers! No need to shout even if you're excited.. writing in lower case will be much more readable. You can load different page into different div by clicking different button, see my last edit for the required code. Anyway, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your original problem. :-)

Comment: One last Question Wiz...Is it possible for me to add a string value to the url while it displays the new page in the div? i hope to use this string value for some query functions on the page that loads into the div space...any chance that might work?

Comment: @Sel not sure what you mean.. if you mean adding to the URL of the page being loaded to the div it's simply `$("#OtherPagePanel").load("/EntryForms/OpenCase.aspx?something=somevalue");` but user won't see it anywhere. Or do you mean the "visible" URL of the browser?

Comment: thats exactly what i want to do...pass some string to the page loading in the div through the URL. when its from one page to the other and it is string i know it looks like this response.redirect("/EntryForms/OpenCase.aspx?something=" + somestringvalue, false). But i wasnt sure how this would turn out since its handled in the code behind and more so in the master page. was kinda skeptical it might backfire...but id give yours suggestion a try and see if it works out.

Comment: And em..could you please take some little time and have a look at this post for me? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682619/what-are-the-possibilities-of-displaying-items-in-a-listbox) am still have a hard time working out some answer for it..thanks

Comment: @Sel did you try my suggestion? Any luck? Regarding your other question sounds like you need `DataGridView`, personally I have no experience with it so can't give full details but that's the direction you should take. Change the tags to `asp.net` and `c#` to get more attention there, the tags you chose are pretty rare.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a postback trigger or an async postback trigger?

i think you can register controls as post back or async on a script manager level with:

Control oControl;

ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(oControl);

you could try that

Comment: Am actually new to this and trying to do lots of reading to get it work...i sorted some advise and was told to use an async postback trigger. but am not sure how to apply it. if you can look from my code and tell, that would be great or i could use some similar example you you know of any...I could also show you what am working on if you dont mind but that would require showing you a realtime display of my screen through skype .

Comment: Hi, Sorry I cant be more assistance at the moment as im at work. I think an update panel trigger must go inside the update panel in the long run. You might be able to make the update panels public properties for the content pages and call something like. (Content1.Content as PageType).UpdatePanel.Update(); and (Content2.Content as PageType).UpdatePanel.Update() but not sure if that is possible or not