# What are the possibilities of displaying items in a listbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, webforms

I've been trying to figure out for a long time now how to create an interface that can allows users to input several rows of data and pass those entries into an SQL server database all in one shot. I could not get any better ideas so I came up with this (see picture below).
[image]

What I envisioned is that the user enters values in the textboxes and hits the "add to list" button. The values are then populated in the list box below with the heading "exhibits lists" and when the add exhibit button is pressed, all values from the list box are passed into the database.

Well, I'm left wondering again if it would be possible to tie these values from the textboxes to the list box and whether I'd be able to pass them into the database.

If it were possible then I'd please love to know how to go about it otherwise I'd be glad if you could recommend a better way for me to handle the situation otherwise I'd have to resolve to data entry one at a time.

I believe there is some useful information from this website that can help solve my problem but I just can't make heads or tails of the article... it seems like I'm almost there and it skids off. Can everyone please read and help me adapt it to my situation? Post below:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ExtendedGridView.aspx

Comment: Maybe I'm not following you entirely, but what is stopping you from accessing the data fields individually like  `string value = textbox.Text`, going through all of the input fields, and building up your insertion query like that?

Comment: That would unfortunately be a last resort. the analogy here is that several exhibits(Exhibit Type, Exhibit Image...etc..) can be registered to one case (CaseID). SO instead of doing that one by one where id pick the values and insert one at a time, i was hoping there could be a better interface to accept multiple entries that i could tie to the (CASEID) and pass the insertion at once or better still i could use this method where each entry into the (Exhibit Type, Exhibit Image...etc..) is temporarily held in the list box and after the user is done with the list of exhibits that have to be

Comment: registered to the case, they hit add exhibit button and the values from the text box is inserted into the database with some sort of for each loop. That is if anything like that was possible...but if either way was possible and there wasnt any ideas, then id have no choice than to resort to inserting one at a time.which in would probably make the design less time efficient...:(..loosing some marks there...

Comment: Why you need to send the whole data at a time. If so how will you differentiate and write them in to each and separate column. Adding to listbox is not a matter but inserting the whole data together is not good

Comment: @Dorababu- Because i wish to save time by allowing users to perform action just once but the insert can run in for each loops until no more occurrences available...I hope that does not sound like garbage??

Comment: The referenced CodeProject article is similiar to what you want, but it will not easily adapt to what you need. It describes extending a control. What you want is a data-entry-form above a data-grid.

Comment: @Dorababu: "inserting the whole data together is not good" ADO.NET is designed to make these kinds of bulk inserts, updates, and deletes through the `DataAdapter`. Therefore, it is good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I have done this twice before.

Check out the "Data Access Tutorials" at http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data for ideas.

#### Overview

- For the user-interface, you want a data-entry-form above a data-grid.
- For the back-end, you want a data-adapter (or table-adapter) that loads and saves data to the database in one operation.

You would use a `DataSet` and `DataAdapter` to update the database, and manipulate a `DataRow` for the input and a `DataTable` for the list-box. Note the list-box is actually a data-grid, repeater, or other control that accepts a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`.

- The `DataAdapter` fills the `DataSet` which contains the `DataTable`.
- The input controls bind to a `DataRow` created from the `DataTable`. When the user clicks add-to-list, you add the data-row to the data-table, then create a new data-row for the next item.
- When the user clicks add-exhibit, it is a simple matter of using the `DataAdapter` to update the database. Any changed, deleted, and added data is handled for you.

Comment: Oh! gracious.... AMissico!... why did you keep me waiting for so long....Thanks very much...if i went that way would i be capable of handling insert as well?

Comment: @Selase: Yes. Inserts as well.

Comment: AMissico!..can you give me one example of how to opulate the data list with data entered into the textboxes...I couldt figure that out from the link you provided. And if you could also add one example of how to update the database with values from the datalist. COunting dearly on your rapid response. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a transaction to encapsulate all the sql queries you are trying to run, so you can then just 'commit' the transaction in one to the database? Are you still having difficulty with this issue?